# Should we add a comma before 'and'?

Tags: commas

My desire to become an excellent accountant makes me enthusiastic, motivated, focused, and an excellent fit for this job.

Is it right to put a comma before "and" ?

Answer (score 4):

### Answer to your question

Comma or no comma is accepted.

According to https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

> Use of the Oxford comma is stylistic, meaning that some style guides
>   demand its use while others don’t.

But, personally I think it's a good habit to use it, one reason being because it prevents what above article refers to as "strange misunderstandings".

### By the way

The structure of your sentence should be grammatically reconsidered. Although joining different parts of speech by a conjunction like "and" is done sometimes informal speech, from a "strictly speaking" perspective, the list should include only one part of speech:

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Coordinating_conjunctions

> Coordinating conjunctions, also called coordinators, are conjunctions
>   that join, or coordinate, two or more items (such as words, main
>   clauses, or sentences) of equal syntactic importance.

I interpret "syntactic importance" to include part of speech. If it really doesn't, in this case it still wouldn't hurt to err on the side of strict interpretation.

On that note:

In your sentence, the following function as adjectives:

- enthusiastic
- motivated
- focused

However, the following functions as a noun:

- fit

So, *one* way to start restructuring is the following:

> My desire to become an excellent accountant makes me enthusiastic, motivated, and focused, and it makes me an excellent fit for the job.

Changing the meaning a little bit for conciseness, we can use the following:

> I am an excellent fit for the job because my desire to become an excellent accountant makes me enthusiastic, motivated, and focused.

Tying everything back to your original question, note that I used the Oxford comma :)